# convert json data to array in javascript for specific format

Tags: javascript, format, fetch-api

Im working on leaflet map, I need to place some points in the map.
I made API in PHP that output data i want in json and i get it in javascript, but i need to make good format to work with leaflet..

```
   async function get_data() {
        let obj;
        const res = await fetch('api.php')
        obj = await res.json();
        console.log(obj)
    }

    get_data();
```

I get this result in console:

[image]

but what I need is

```
let points = [
    ["43.6045", 1.444, "point 1"],
    [43.60, 1.444, "point 2"],
];
```

should you be like that in console:

[image]

if someone have any idea how to do this it would really help me!

Thanks you, have a nice day.

Comment: Why is `"43.6045"` a string and `43.60` a number? Also please share what you have already tried?

Comment: Can be a string or a number, leaflet accept both

Comment: yeah but if you gonna make a function to create an array with a specific format, then make it simpler, keep them all as numbers or strings, not like the example you gave

Comment: That's not my question. The input shows `latitude` to be a string, but the output has one number and one string. I assume this is a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map your `obj` result:

```
const points = obj.map(
    ({latitude, longitude, denomination}) => [latitude, longitude, denomination]
);
```

Note that your `obj` is not an *object*. It's an *array*.